# Difference between include app symbols and strip debug symbols during copy?

Tags: ios, debug-symbols

In my project, under build settings i have different configurations, and I can specify weather I want to `strip debug symbols during copy`.

[image]

No when I archive my app, I have option to "include app symbols" for my application:

[image]

Are these two reffering to same thing? As I understand it, these symbols are needed, so I can have more descriptive crash logs, instead of some memory locations. So, it is recommended for debug builds to have these symbols included in IPA, but for releases on apple store I would want to strip them.

Answer (score 1):

"Strip Debug Symbols" refers to stripping them from the binary. You still have the dSYM that contains debug info.

"Include app symbols" I believe means upload the dSYMs too and not just the binary.